# Packager is not automatically launched when using RN cli for iOS builds

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-cli

I'm having trouble with running `react-native run-ios` in *any* RN project on my computer (including if I start a brand new project from scratch). Unless I manually start the packager using `react-native start` before running `react-native run-ios`, the build will fail with the error:

> Port 8081 already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly

It's important to note that **port 8081 is not in use** on my computer. I've tried different ports as well, but the error is **not** caused by port collision, which is the case in basically every other SO question related to this error.

The problem does also *not* occur if I use Xcode to run or build the project, it *only* happens when I use the RN CLI.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had Nodechef CLI installed, which hi-jacks the "nc" command which is used in the startup build to run Netcat.